# Copy from QTreeView to QTreeView

Tags: c++, qt

I have 2 QTreeViews. The first QtreeView has items, the second QTreeview is empty. I want to copy selected item from 1st QtreeView to second. And I want to save the structure of 1st QtreeView. For example, structure of 1st QTreeView:

> item_1 
> --item_2 
> --item_3 
> ----item_4

At first, I copy item_3 and past into 2nd QTreeView. 2nd QTreeView should look:

> item_3 
> --item_4

Then I copy item_2. 2nd QTreeView should look:

> item_2 
> item_3 
> --item_4

And finaly I copy item_1. 2nd QTreeView should look:

> item_1 
> --item_2 
> --item_3 
> ----item_4

How to do that?

Comment: Why do you need to copy items if two trees can have the same model and, as a result, the same content.

Comment: At first, I want to edit items in 2nd QTreeView. Also I want to make this function obly for myself.